# the difference between multiple active record objects on a given timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have a simple problem: imagine a calendar with 1:N events. at some point i would like to know what is changed between two timestamps.

- which events where created, updated or destroyed?
- i don not need to know about events which are created after the first timestamp, and destroyed before the second timestamp.

i experimented with papertrail, but it seems to me that there should be an simpler way to do that.

simple right ? :)

**UPDATE: fetching created and updated records:**

```
Calendar.last.events.where("created_at >= :timestamp OR updated_at >= :timestamp", {timestamp: timestamp})
```

**UPDATE: fetching destroyed records through papertrail:**

```
PaperTrail::EventVersions.where("created_at >= :timestamp", { timestamp: DateTime.now}).where(calendar_id: calendar.id, event: "destroy")
```

note: you need to add a metadata reference to the (custom) verion model.

**UPDATE:**
@ck3g suggested "soft deletes", after reading this [post](http://railspikes.com/2010/2/26/acts-as-archive). i decided to rethink my model. Meaning: If an *event* has a user assigned to it, i have to "cancel" (not delete) the event. if it has no association i can safely destroy the event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should perform some kind of soft delete (archive) records. You can find a bunch of realizations in the web. Later you can find records by `deleted_at`.

Comment: good point, after reading this http://railspikes.com/2010/2/26/acts-as-archive i decided to rethink my model (event destroyed VS event cancelled.)